# yum update centos 5.5 ERROR with rpm_check_debug vs depsolve

Tags: centos, yum

Having some issues with yum update on my centos box.
It seems there's some issue with 32 and 64 bit libraries, but i am not sure how can i resolve this.
This server is a production server and i would like to resolve it with as minimal interruption as possible.
would appreciate any help!

```
[root@xxx ~]uname -a
Linux ip-xxx 2.6.16.33-xenU #2 SMP Wed Aug 15 17:27:36 SAST 2007 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@xxx ~]yum update
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.symnds.com
 * extras: www.gtlib.gatech.edu
 * rpmforge: mirror.lug.udel.edu
 * updates: mirrors.mit.edu
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies

.
.
.
.

Updating:
 bind-libs                            i386                     30:9.3.6-25.P1.el5_11.2                      updates                         866 k
 device-mapper                        i386                     1.02.67-2.el5_11.1                           updates                         804 k
 krb5-devel                           i386                     1.6.1-80.el5_11                              updates                         1.9 M
 krb5-libs                            i386                     1.6.1-80.el5_11                              updates                         670 k
 libXfont                             i386                     1.2.2-1.0.6.el5_11                           updates                         242 k
 libxml2                              i386                     2.6.26-2.1.25.el5_11                         updates                         799 k
 mod-pagespeed-beta                   i386                     1.9.32.2-4321                                mod-pagespeed                   5.7 M
 nss                                  i386                     3.16.2.3-1.el5_11                            updates                         1.2 M
 openssl                              i686                     0.9.8e-31.el5_11                             updates                         1.5 M
 openssl-devel                        i386                     0.9.8e-31.el5_11                             updates                         1.9 M
 perl                                 i386                     4:5.8.8-43.el5_11                            updates                          12 M
 popt                                 i386                     1.10.2.3-36.el5_11                           updates                          77 k
 rpm-libs                             i386                     4.4.2.3-36.el5_11                            updates                         931 k
Installing for dependencies:
 bind-libs                            x86_64                   30:9.3.6-20.P1.el5_8.6                       base                            898 k
 bzip2-libs                           x86_64                   1.0.3-6.el5_5                                base                             35 k
 device-mapper                        x86_64                   1.02.67-2.el5                                base                            831 k
 e2fsprogs-libs                       x86_64                   1.39-37.el5                                  base                            120 k
 elfutils-libelf                      x86_64                   0.137-3.el5                                  base                             53 k
 glibc                                x86_64                   2.5-123                                      base                            4.8 M
 keyutils-libs                        x86_64                   1.2-1.el5                                    base                             17 k
 krb5-libs                            x86_64                   1.6.1-78.el5                                 base                            682 k
 libgcc                               x86_64                   4.1.2-55.el5                                 base                            100 k
 libselinux                           x86_64                   1.33.4-5.7.el5                               base                             78 k
 libsepol                             x86_64                   1.15.2-3.el5                                 base                            131 k
 ncurses                              x86_64                   5.5-24.20060715                              base                            1.2 M
 nspr                                 x86_64                   4.10.6-1.el5_10                              base                            123 k
 nss                                  x86_64                   3.16.1-4.el5_11                              updates                         1.3 M
 openssl                              x86_64                   0.9.8e-31.el5_11                             updates                         1.5 M
 popt                                 x86_64                   1.10.2.3-34.el5                              base                             79 k
 readline                             x86_64                   5.1-3.el5                                    base                            228 k
 rpm                                  x86_64                   4.4.2.3-36.el5_11                            updates                         1.2 M
 rpm-libs                             x86_64                   4.4.2.3-34.el5                               base                            926 k
 sqlite                               x86_64                   3.3.6-7                                      base                            207 k
 zlib                                 x86_64                   1.2.3-7.el5                                  base                             52 k

Transaction Summary
Install      21 Package(s)
Upgrade      13 Package(s)

Total size: 42 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y

Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
ERROR with rpm_check_debug vs depsolve:
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by openssl-devel-0.9.8e-31.el5_11.i386
libssl.so.6 is needed by openssl-devel-0.9.8e-31.el5_11.i386
libgssapi_krb5.so.2()(64bit) is needed by openssl-0.9.8e-31.el5_11.x86_64
libk5crypto.so.3()(64bit) is needed by openssl-0.9.8e-31.el5_11.x86_64
libk5crypto.so.3(k5crypto_3_MIT)(64bit) is needed by openssl-0.9.8e-31.el5_11.x86_64
libkrb5.so.3()(64bit) is needed by openssl-0.9.8e-31.el5_11.x86_64
libkrb5.so.3(krb5_3_MIT)(64bit) is needed by openssl-0.9.8e-31.el5_11.x86_64
libnss3.so()(64bit) is needed by rpm-4.4.2.3-36.el5_11.x86_64
libnssutil3.so()(64bit) is needed by rpm-4.4.2.3-36.el5_11.x86_64
libpopt.so.0()(64bit) is needed by rpm-4.4.2.3-36.el5_11.x86_64
librpm-4.4.so()(64bit) is needed by rpm-4.4.2.3-36.el5_11.x86_64
librpmbuild-4.4.so()(64bit) is needed by rpm-4.4.2.3-36.el5_11.x86_64
librpmdb-4.4.so()(64bit) is needed by rpm-4.4.2.3-36.el5_11.x86_64
librpmio-4.4.so()(64bit) is needed by rpm-4.4.2.3-36.el5_11.x86_64
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by bind-libs-9.3.6-25.P1.el5_11.2.i386
libdevmapper.so.1.02()(64bit) is needed by e2fsprogs-libs-1.39-37.el5.x86_64
rpm-libs is needed by (installed) rpm-python-4.4.2.3-34.el5.i386
rpm-libs is needed by (installed) rpm-build-4.4.2.3-34.el5.i386
device-mapper is needed by (installed) device-mapper-event-1.02.67-2.el5.i386
popt is needed by (installed) rpm-python-4.4.2.3-34.el5.i386
popt is needed by (installed) rpm-build-4.4.2.3-34.el5.i386
nss is needed by (installed) nss-tools-3.16.1-4.el5_11.i386
krb5-libs is needed by (installed) krb5-workstation-1.6.1-78.el5.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) pam_ccreds-3-5.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) tcpdump-3.9.4-15.el5.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) stunnel-4.15-2.el5.1.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) fipscheck-1.2.0-1.el5.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) perl-DBD-MySQL-3.0007-2.el5.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) libc-client-2004g-2.2.1.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) php-common-5.3.4-1.w5.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) php-cli-5.3.4-1.w5.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) php-5.3.4-1.w5.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) php-mysql-5.3.4-1.w5.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) php-imap-5.3.4-1.w5.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) neon-0.25.5-10.el5_4.1.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) python-ldap-2.2.0-2.1.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) perl-Net-SSLeay-1.36-1.el5.rfx.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) sendmail-8.13.8-8.1.el5_7.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) openssh-4.3p2-82.el5.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) openssh-clients-4.3p2-82.el5.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) openssh-server-4.3p2-82.el5.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) wget-1.11.4-3.el5_8.2.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) cyrus-sasl-2.1.22-7.el5_8.1.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) cyrus-sasl-devel-2.1.22-7.el5_8.1.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) ipsec-tools-0.6.5-14.el5_8.5.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) bind-utils-9.3.6-20.P1.el5_8.6.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) mysql-5.0.95-5.el5_9.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) vsftpd-2.0.5-28.el5.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) mysql-server-5.0.95-5.el5_9.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) python-libs-2.4.3-56.el5.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) m2crypto-0.16-9.el5.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) ruby-libs-1.8.5-31.el5_9.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) gnome-vfs2-2.16.2-12.el5_9.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) curl-7.15.5-17.el5_9.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) elinks-0.11.1-8.el5_9.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) openldap-2.3.43-28.el5_10.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) subversion-1.6.11-12.el5_10.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) postgresql-libs-8.1.23-10.el5_10.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) gnupg-1.4.5-18.el5_10.1.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) httpd-2.2.3-91.el5.centos.i386
libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) wpa_supplicant-0.5.10-10.el5.i386
libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) stunnel-4.15-2.el5.1.i386
libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) perl-DBD-MySQL-3.0007-2.el5.i386
libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) libc-client-2004g-2.2.1.i386
libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) php-common-5.3.4-1.w5.i386
libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) php-cli-5.3.4-1.w5.i386
libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) php-5.3.4-1.w5.i386
libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) php-mysql-5.3.4-1.w5.i386
libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) php-imap-5.3.4-1.w5.i386
libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) neon-0.25.5-10.el5_4.1.i386
libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) python-ldap-2.2.0-2.1.i386
libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) perl-Net-SSLeay-1.36-1.el5.rfx.i386
libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) sendmail-8.13.8-8.1.el5_7.i386
libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) wget-1.11.4-3.el5_8.2.i386
libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) mysql-5.0.95-5.el5_9.i386
libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) vsftpd-2.0.5-28.el5.i386
libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) mysql-server-5.0.95-5.el5_9.i386
libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) quota-3.13-8.el5.i386
libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) python-libs-2.4.3-56.el5.i386
libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) m2crypto-0.16-9.el5.i386
libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) ruby-libs-1.8.5-31.el5_9.i386
libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) gnome-vfs2-2.16.2-12.el5_9.i386
libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) curl-7.15.5-17.el5_9.i386
libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) elinks-0.11.1-8.el5_9.i386
libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) openldap-2.3.43-28.el5_10.i386
libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) subversion-1.6.11-12.el5_10.i386
libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) postgresql-libs-8.1.23-10.el5_10.i386
libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) gnupg-1.4.5-18.el5_10.1.i386
libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) httpd-2.2.3-91.el5.centos.i386
libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) wpa_supplicant-0.5.10-10.el5.i386
rpm is needed by (installed) rpm-python-4.4.2.3-34.el5.i386
rpm is needed by (installed) rpm-build-4.4.2.3-34.el5.i386
bind-libs is needed by (installed) bind-utils-9.3.6-20.P1.el5_8.6.i386
Complete!
(1, [u'Please report this error in http://bugs.centos.org/yum5bug'])
```

Comment: Does running `yum clean all` and then trying again help/change anything? Does `package-cleanup --problems` report anything?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Etan. No, no problems reported by package-cleanup --problems. yum clean all does not help at all.

Comment: You get the same results from the update attempt after you run `yum clean all`? What does `yum info bind-libs` return as output?

Comment: yes, same result after yum clean all.
yum info bind-libs : (had to screen capture as the site won't let me paste the whole output) http://i.imgur.com/LNA1Cbj.png

Comment: Can you get the output from `yum -d10 update` (it will be a lot)? Also what happens if you try `yum update bind-libs`?

Comment: thanks a lot for trying to help! here's the output for both http://pastebin.com/ga5J6z7Q

Comment: What does `yum info bind-utils` say? What about `yum update bind-utils`? Something about your repositories or installed packages is confused about versions. `yum` is trying to install an older `bind-utils`/`bind-libs` for `x86_64` than it is for `i386` for some reason.

Comment: here's the output: http://pastebin.com/PbfJgziu i am really not sure what happened and for that matter, why do i even need the i386 packages if my system is x64.

Comment: You already *have* the `i386` versions installed. And *do not* have the `x86_64` versions installed. (At least of `bind-utils`.) Your repo metadata is also seemingly a bit confused as it doesn't list the `i386` updates version of `bind-utils` (which is why I suggested `yum clean all` before to force metadata recreation). What does `yum list installed *.i?86` output?

Comment: that actually starts making sense now. this machine was originally ran as 32bit instance and later on converted to be x64 (it's an amazon ec2 instance). I did not however have any problems until recently to yum update and the machine was converted more than a year ago. here's the output : http://tny.cz/ed65d433

Comment: So the problem is that your packages aren't in a consistent state and the repos seem to be giving you confused results for available updates. As I said you can try to manually rectify the situation here by forcing `bind-utils`/etc. updates for the correct (or probably both) architectures but it may end up being simpler to just migrate to a new machine. You can specify architecture of package to yum when doing an update/install (which you will probably need to do to get yourself out of this situation).

Comment: this was actually the last resort before migrating to a fresh machine. think it'll be wiser. thanks a lot for your help Etan!